# Validating usernames using regular expressions

Tags: regex, reactjs

I have to validate a username in reactJs.
The conditions are-

1. It should be alphanumeric
2. Should be greater than 5 characters and less than 11 characters
3. Should not start with a digit

My solution is not working:

```
value.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,10}/)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change `{6,10}` to `{5,9}` since `[a-zA-Z]` has already represent a character

```
value.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already matching 1 character in the first character class `[a-zA-Z]`.

To match greater than 5 characters and less than 11 characters you could use `{5,9}` as a quantifier for the second character class and assert the end of the line `$` to prevent [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) from returning the first 9 characters when the string is longer than 9 characters.

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCAhyO/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "A123456789BBBBBBB",
  "A123456789"
];
let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$/;
strings.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value.match(pattern));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use lookaheads to validate the string with some rules.

You could use this pattern `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,11}$)(?!\d).+`.

This `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,11}$)` assures, that what follows beginning of a string `^` is 5 to 11 alphanumerics.

Second, negative, lookahead is `(?!\d)` to prevent from matching, when digit is first character in a string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m33jOF/1)

Read [this for reference](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password).